# Get data from another collection in same database mongoose, ejs

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, ejs, mongoose-schema

I made a web application that uses Firebase for storage and MongoDB atlas as a database. I made a schema that stores file paths and titles for one section. Then I also added another schema to my app in order to create another collection in the same database. Now the main problem that I am facing is that I am not able to retrieve data from my second collection to my index.ejs page. Here is my code:

```
//MongoDB init
mongoose.connect(
  "mongodb+srv://<My_DB>:<MY_DB_pass>@cluster0.cqqda.mongodb.net/proDB?retryWrites=true&w=majority"
);

mongoose.set("useCreateIndex", true);

const connectionParams = {
  useNewUrlParser: true,
  useCreateIndex: true,
  useUnifiedTopology: true,
};

mongoose
  .connect(url, connectionParams)
  .then(() => {
    console.log("Connected to database ");
  })
  .catch((err) => {
    console.error(`Error connecting to the database. \n${err}`);
  });

mongoose.set("useCreateIndex", true);
const dbName = "proDB";

const userSchema = mongoose.Schema({
  title: String,
  filepath: String,
});

const testSchema = mongoose.Schema({
  secondTitle: String,
  secondFilePath: String,
});

testSchema.plugin(findOrCreate);

userSchema.plugin(passportLocalMongoose);
userSchema.plugin(findOrCreate);

//DATABASE MODEL
const User = new mongoose.model("User", userSchema);
const Test = new mongoose.model("Test", testSchema);
```

**Index route:**

```
app.get("/", function (req, res) {
  User.find({}, function (err, foundItems) {
    // console.log(foundItems);
    res.render("index", { newListItems: foundItems });
  });
});
```

**EJS code:**
*This code renders data from my first collection*

```
<% newListItems.forEach(function(item){ %>
                        <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 video-div " >
                            <!-- before col-sm -->
                            <div class="main-video">
                                <video style="outline: none; width: 100%; height: 200px;" 
                                    width="auto" 
                                   height="220" controls>
                                    <source src="<%=item.filepath%>" type="video/mp4">
                                </video>
                            </div>
                            <div class="video-title" style="width: 50%;">
                                <p class="podcast-title">
                                    <%=item.title%>
                                </p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <% }) %>
```

*Second EJS code that in which I am trying to render data from my second collection*

```
<% newListItems.forEach(function(item){ %>
                    <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 video-div ">
                        <!-- before col-sm -->
                        <div class="main-video">
                            <video style="outline: none; width: 100%; height: 200px;" width="auto" 
                                height="220"
                                controls>
                                <source src="<%=item.secondFilePath%>" type="video/mp4">
                            </video>
                            <!-- <img style="width: 100%; height: auto;" src="" alt=""> -->
                        </div>
                        <div class="video-title" style="width: 50%;">
                            <p class="podcast-title">
                                <%=item.secondPodcastTitle%>
                            </p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <% }) %>
```

Comment: Do both EJS blocks live in the same file? Do they both appear in `index`?

Comment: @codemonkey yes both the blocks are in the same file index.ejs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your route function to query the other collection as well:

```
app.get("/", function (req, res) {
  User.find()
    .then(newListItems => {
      Test.find() // <- Your other collection
        .then(testListItems => {
          res.render("index", { newListItems, testListItems });
        })
    })
});
```

Then in your EJS, do this:

```
                     <% newListItems.forEach(function(item){ %>
                        <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 video-div " >
                            <!-- before col-sm -->
                            <div class="main-video">
                                <video style="outline: none; width: 100%; height: 200px;" 
                                    width="auto" 
                                   height="220" controls>
                                    <source src="<%=item.filepath%>" type="video/mp4">
                                </video>
                            </div>
                            <div class="video-title" style="width: 50%;">
                                <p class="podcast-title">
                                    <%=item.title%>
                                </p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                     <% }) %>
...
...
                 <% testListItems.forEach(function(item){ %>
                    <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 video-div ">
                        <!-- before col-sm -->
                        <div class="main-video">
                            <video style="outline: none; width: 100%; height: 200px;" width="auto" 
                                height="220"
                                controls>
                                <source src="<%=item.secondFilePath%>" type="video/mp4">
                            </video>
                            <!-- <img style="width: 100%; height: auto;" src="" alt=""> -->
                        </div>
                        <div class="video-title" style="width: 50%;">
                            <p class="podcast-title">
                                <%=item.secondTitle%>
                            </p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                  <% }) %>
```

Note that you had `<%=item.secondPodcastTitle%>` in your original ejs. This is not consistent with your schema which does not have `secondPodcastTitle`. It has `secondTitle` so I change the ejs to: `<%=item.secondTitle%>`